How do i remove padding on top of SingleChildScrollView / Column
Im not sure where the padding is coming from, but there is a space at the top that i want remove.
I have tried chatgpt/claude all day but its not helping.
everything works.
I didnt find a stackover flow that was similar aside from this one but it didnt help:
Make Listeview work nested inside of column inside of a container in flutter

here is the full code all in one snip::
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class BoardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BoardWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<BoardWidget> createState() => _BoardWidgetState();
}

class _BoardWidgetState extends State<BoardWidget> {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _reports = [
    {'sys_id': 1, 'sys_title': 'Item 1', 'sys_data_display_type': 'donut'},
    {'sys_id': 2, 'sys_title': 'Item 2', 'sys_data_display_type': 'bar'},
    {'sys_id': 3, 'sys_title': 'Item 3', 'sys_data_display_type': 'donut'},
  ];

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _grid_reports_to_sections = [
    // Example: {'sys_id': 1, 'section': 'section-id', 'position': Offset(0, 0), 'size': const Size(100, 100)},
  ];

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _sections = [
    {"sys_id": Uuid().v4(), "sys_title": ""}
  ];

  int _section_count = 1;
  bool _isDraggingFromLeft = false;

  void _addSection() {
    setState(() {
      _sections.add({"sys_id": Uuid().v4(), "sys_title": ""});
      _section_count++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          // LEFT SIDE
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: ListView(
              children: _reports.map((item) {
                return Draggable<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                  data: item,
                  feedback: Material(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Opacity(
                      opacity: 0.7,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            item['sys_title'],
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 4.0), // Add space between title and subtitle
                          Text(
                            item['sys_data_display_type'], // Assuming you have a 'sys_subtitle' key in your item map
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  childWhenDragging: Opacity(
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(item['sys_title']),
                      subtitle: Text(item['sys_data_display_type']),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onDragStarted: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isDraggingFromLeft = true;
                    });
                  },
                  onDragEnd: (_) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isDraggingFromLeft = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item['sys_title']),
                    subtitle: Text(item['sys_data_display_type']),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),

          // RIGHT SIDE
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
  
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: _sections.map((section) {
                      final sectionId = section['sys_id'];

                      return Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text("SECTION ${_sections.indexOf(section) + 1}", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: 500,
                              child: LayoutBuilder(
                                builder: (context, constraints) {
                                  return DragTarget<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                                    onWillAccept: (details) {
                                      bool existingItem = _grid_reports_to_sections.any((item) => item['sys_id'] == details!['sys_id'] && item['section'] == sectionId);
                                      return (!existingItem && _isDraggingFromLeft) || (existingItem && !_isDraggingFromLeft);
                                    },
                                    onAcceptWithDetails: (details) {
                                      final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                                      final localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.offset);
                                      final itemSize = const Size(100, 100); // Default size or you can handle custom sizes
                                      final gridSize = 20.0;

                                      Offset snappedOffset = Offset(
                                        (localOffset.dx / gridSize).round() * gridSize,
                                        (localOffset.dy / gridSize).round() * gridSize,
                                      );

                                      snappedOffset = Offset(
                                        snappedOffset.dx.clamp(0, constraints.maxWidth - itemSize.width),
                                        snappedOffset.dy.clamp(0, constraints.maxHeight - itemSize.height),
                                      );

                                      final newItem = {
                                        'sys_id': details.data['sys_id'],
                                        'section': sectionId,
                                        'position': snappedOffset,
                                        'size': itemSize,
                                      };

                                      setState(() {
                                        if (_isDraggingFromLeft) {
                                          _grid_reports_to_sections.add(newItem);
                                        } else {
                                          final existingItem = _grid_reports_to_sections.firstWhere((item) => item['sys_id'] == newItem['sys_id'] && item['section'] == sectionId);
                                          existingItem['position'] = snappedOffset;
                                        }
                                      });
                                    },
                                    builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                                      return Stack(
                                        children: [
                                          CustomPaint(
                                            painter: GridPainter(),
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                              height: constraints.maxHeight,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          ..._grid_reports_to_sections.where((item) => item['section'] == sectionId).map((item) {
                                            return Positioned(
                                              left: (item['position'] as Offset).dx,
                                              top: (item['position'] as Offset).dy,
                                              child: Draggable<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                                                data: item,
                                                feedback: Material(
                                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    height: (item['size'] as Size).height,
                                                    width: (item['size'] as Size).width,
                                                    child: Center(child: Text(_reports.firstWhere((report) => report['sys_id'] == item['sys_id'])['sys_title'])),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                childWhenDragging: Container(),
                                                onDragStarted: () {
                                                  item['originalPosition'] = item['position'];
                                                },
                                                child: Container(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  height: (item['size'] as Size).height,
                                                  width: (item['size'] as Size).width,
                                                  child: Stack(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Center(child: Text(_reports.firstWhere((report) => report['sys_id'] == item['sys_id'])['sys_title'])),
                                                      Positioned(
                                                        bottom: 0,
                                                        right: 0,
                                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                                          onPanUpdate: (details) {
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              final newSize = Size(
                                                                ((item['size'] as Size).width + details.delta.dx).clamp(20.0, constraints.maxWidth - (item['position'] as Offset).dx),
                                                                ((item['size'] as Size).height + details.delta.dy).clamp(20.0, constraints.maxHeight - (item['position'] as Offset).dy),
                                                              );

                                                              if (_canGrow(item, newSize)) {
                                                                item['size'] = newSize;
                                                              }
                                                            });
                                                          },
                                                          child: Container(
                                                            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                                                            height: 30,
                                                            width: 30,
                                                            child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle, color: Colors.white),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 10,
                  right: 10,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _addSection,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  bool _canGrow(Map<String, dynamic> item, Size newSize) {
    for (var otherItem in _grid_reports_to_sections) {
      if (otherItem == item || otherItem['section'] != item['section']) continue;

      final itemRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
        (item['position'] as Offset).dx,
        (item['position'] as Offset).dy,
        newSize.width,
        newSize.height,
      );
      final otherRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
        (otherItem['position'] as Offset).dx,
        (otherItem['position'] as Offset).dy,
        (otherItem['size'] as Size).width,
        (otherItem['size'] as Size).height,
      );

      if (itemRect.overlaps(otherRect)) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool _isOverlappingWithOtherItems(Map<String, dynamic> item, {Map<String, dynamic>? excludeItem}) {
    final itemRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      (item['position'] as Offset).dx,
      (item['position'] as Offset).dy,
      (item['size'] as Size).width,
      (item['size'] as Size).height,
    );

    for (var otherItem in _grid_reports_to_sections) {
      if (otherItem == item || otherItem == excludeItem) continue;

      final otherRect = Rect.fromLTWH(
        (otherItem['position'] as Offset).dx,
        (otherItem['position'] as Offset).dy,
        (otherItem['size'] as Size).width,
        (otherItem['size'] as Size).height,
      );

      if (itemRect.overlaps(otherRect)) return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}

class GridPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final gridSize = 20.0;
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2);

    for (double x = 0; x <= size.width; x += gridSize) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(x, 0), Offset(x, size.height), paint);
    }
    for (double y = 0; y <= size.height; y += gridSize) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, y), Offset(size.width, y), paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}


Add CrossAxisAlidnment in row then check:
  Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [...]
  )

